# Amiga 500+ does not start up

Tags: amiga, amiga-500

Amiga 500+ does not start up. It has been offline for a considerable amount of time.

The machine powers up but does not move from that point.
I have inserted the workbench disk.
Can anyone advise the best way to connect to a TV set

Comment: You need to give us a bit more information.  What do you mean by "powers up but does not move"?  Also, connected to a TV set would be a different question.  Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Some information you could include in your question to give us a better chance of helping you: Does the power light come on? Does the disk activity light come on, and can you hear whether the disk is being read?

Answer (score 4):

When you switch on an Amiga, you should expect to see the following:

1. The power light will illuminate, slightly dimmed.
2. About half a second later, the power light will brighten.
3. Usually 3-4 seconds later (but could be up to a minute for Amiga models with HD controllers), the floppy drive will start to make noises.

For this check to work, you need only plug in the power supply. There's no need to plug in anything else, not even a TV or monitor - in fact, unplugging everything is recommended in case it's a peripheral that is actually faulty and preventing the Amiga from starting.

If you do not get any power light, then it is likely that the PSU has failed, but could also indicate a fault with the Amiga mainboard.

If you get a dim power light, but it does not brighten a moment later, then you have a good PSU, but there is a fault with the computer.

If you get a dim and then bright power light, then you likely have only a minor fault - perhaps the floppy drive has seized up.

You may also find [this question and answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/863/ive-taken-my-amiga-computer-out-of-storage-after-several-years-and-it-doesnt-w) useful.

Unfortunately because you have a 500 Plus which has not been used for a long time, then it is very likely that you have a damaged computer. The 500 Plus has an onboard alkaline battery which leaks as it ages. It is very likely that this battery has leaked corrosive alkaline over the mainboard and caused damage. Such damage is often repairable by a retro computer specialist.

Even if you decide that you do not want to repair the computer, I would urge you to not throw it away. Some spare parts for Amigas are in short supply. Even if the mainboard has been extensively damaged by battery alkaline, there will still be many salvageable parts that an Amiga specialist would find useful.

Comment: In line with Chunmunka's comment on the question, I've not answered the part about connecting to a TV set since each question should be asked separately. If you'd like to ask a new question about connecting to a TV I'd be happy to answer.